# Android layout problems in unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, ui-testing

I want to test my custom view (MyView) which is used in custom activity (MyActivity). For that I created :

```
public class MyViewTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> ...
```

My custom view has touch and click logic which I want to test. And I need to check coordinates, heights and widths of subviews in my custom view. The first test works fine, as expected. Problems appears with the next test. For some reason, coordinates, heights and widths of all views in MyView are 0.

What may cause this problem? I tried to change the order of tests, but still the first one is passed and the second one is failed. As I understand, after every test MyActivity should be recreated. But what about the layout of it?